# como obtener todos los campos de un json en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var json =    {
     "0":{
       "id": "1",
       "nombre":"zanahoria",
       "categorias":{
         "nombre":'vegetal',
         "id":"3",
         },
         {
         "nombre":'naranja',
         "id":"2",
         },
       }
    }

for (let i in json) {
    for (let j in json[i]) {
         console.log(json[i][j]['categorias'])
    }
}
```

El objeto json es una respuesta de un servicio que cree que contiene esta misma estructura json, al final lo que me arroja console.log(...) es undefined

Comment: aclaro que puede ser en vanilla o en jquery, cualquiera de las dos respuestas me serviría, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias poner los valores de `categorias` entre corchetes `[` al crear el `json`

```
"categorias":[{
         "nombre":'vegetal',
         "id":"3"
         },
         {
         "nombre":'naranja',
         "id":"2"
         }]
```

en cuanto a obtener los datos del `json` el codigo seria:

```
for (let i in json) {
  for (let j in json[i].categorias) {
    console.log(json[i].categorias[j].nombre)
  }
}
```

Tu codigo quedaria asi:

```js
var json =    {
     "0":{
       "id": "1",
       "nombre":"zanahoria",
       "categorias":[{
         "nombre":'vegetal',
         "id":"3"
         },
         {
         "nombre":'naranja',
         "id":"2"
         }]
       }
    }

for (let i in json) {
  for (let j in json[i].categorias) {
    console.log(json[i].categorias[j].nombre)
  }
}
```